# сайт по страницам

Tags: css3, html5, frontend

Доброй ночи коллеги. Нужен Ваш опыт в верстке сайтов. Как правильно реализовать верстку сайта постранично? То есть, к примеру, у Вас есть Главная страница на которой находится nav, main, footer и эта страница на весь экран, ниже ничего нет и scroll-а нет. Прикреплю пример страницы для более понятного вопроса. Вот как такое правильно реализовать и как это называется, такой тип сайта?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычный сайт, правила те же самые. Только учтите, что количество контента может измениться в конечном счете, поэтому в центральный блок прикручиваем какой-нибудь плагин для красивого скролла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться от jQuery Tab ... смотрите 
три страницы (с фейковыми данными) уместили в одной ..
при умелом обращении с этим можно делать хорошие штуки

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

ul a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

li,
a {
  outline: none !important;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, darkblue, lightblue);
  background-position: center center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

li {
  padding: .4vw .8vw;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}

.item {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item p {
  font-size: .9em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 380px;
  margin: 1vh auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.item-blog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

.post {
  text-align: left!important;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.post h3 {
  padding: 6px;
}

.header-post {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: lightgreen;
  align-items: center;
}

.spans span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.spans span:last-child {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".page").tabs();
  });
</script>

<div class="page">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#a">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">Комьюнити</a></li>
    <li><a href="#c">Блог</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d">Кодим</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Обсуждения</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="items">
    <div id="a" class="item">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt molestias earum doloribus eveniet? Enim modi consequatur ipsam maxime nam officia eveniet, adipisci et temporibus ad quo, doloremque error aliquam repellendus quaerat cupiditate magni
        quam? Eius eligendi dolorem nihil officia minima repellendus sapiente! Mollitia cupiditate, ea fugiat dolores recusandae atque explicabo dicta maiores? Explicabo, dolore aspernatur! Quo, molestiae! Id, facilis neque natus hic perferendis ex aut,
        inventore dolore libero et laborum exercitationem in atque vel minus. Ullam maxime dignissimos dicta et laboriosam fugit officia, distinctio atque saepe voluptas similique aliquid quisquam doloremque assumenda sapiente! Itaque, quod esse odio
        sunt dignissimos placeat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="item">
      <img src="http://4555000.com/wp-content/uploads/busty-babes/Boney-busty-girl-tits.jpg" alt="">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit quisquam ab quas quibusdam nostrum assumenda reiciendis. Voluptatem debitis accusantium doloribus ut pariatur quibusdam odio dolorum, fugiat consequuntur ipsum iusto sit!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="c" class="item item-blog">
      <h2>Блог Invisible Cumunite</h2>
      <div class="blog">
        <div class="post">
          <div class="header-post">
            <h3><a href="">Название поста</a></h3>
            <p class="spans">
              <span>Имя фамилия</span>
              <span>Дата и время публикации</span>
              <span> &#8730; </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных, и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Которое алфавит строчка составитель реторический имеет вдали снова переулка знаках вопрос использовало своего то, возвращайся, предупредила если лучше они
            решила? </p>
        </div>

        <div class="post">
          <div class="header-post">
            <h3><a href="">Название поста</a></h3>
            <p class="spans">
              <span>Имя фамилия</span>
              <span>Дата и время публикации</span>
              <span></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных, и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Которое алфавит строчка составитель реторический имеет вдали снова переулка знаках вопрос использовало своего то, возвращайся, предупредила если лучше они
            решила? </p>
        </div>

        <div class="post">
          <div class="header-post">
            <h3><a href="">Название поста</a></h3>
            <p class="spans">
              <span>Имя фамилия</span>
              <span>Дата и время публикации</span>
              <span></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных, и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Которое алфавит строчка составитель реторический имеет вдали снова переулка знаках вопрос использовало своего то, возвращайся, предупредила если лучше они
            решила? </p>
        </div>

        <div class="post">
          <div class="header-post">
            <h3><a href="">Название поста</a></h3>
            <p class="spans">
              <span>Имя фамилия</span>
              <span>Дата и время публикации</span>
              <span></span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных, и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Которое алфавит строчка составитель реторический имеет вдали снова переулка знаках вопрос использовало своего то, возвращайся, предупредила если лучше они
            решила? </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="d" class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```